# access to a json in javascript file

Tags: asp.net

Hi to all I'm beginner in asp.net I have following Json in my aspx page :

```
 {
    {
        "Status":"<%= this._result.ToString().ToLower() %>" , 
        "SavePath":"<%= this.FileUrl%>" , 
        "FileName":"<%= this.Request["qqfile"] %>",
        "SizeError":"<%= this._sizeError.ToString().ToLower()%>",
        "ImgValidation":"<%=this._Imgvalid.ToString().ToLower()%>"

    }
    }
```

> I need use the json in JS file like blow:

```
if (responseJSON.Status == 'false') {


                $.pushMessage({
                    message: 'خطا در بارگزاری اطلاعات!',
                    messageClass: 'loader-message',
                    delay: 3500
                });
                return;
            }

            else {

                $(options.imgPath).attr("value", responseJSON.SavePath);


                $(options.imgName).html(responseJSON.FileName);
            }
```

> How can I use the json Tanks

Comment: What do you mean "use the json"? You are already using it when you do responseJSON.Status

Comment: Your JSON isn't valid to begin with. Your brackets are nested too deep. You have no way of referring to 'Status' because you have no way of referring to the object that holds 'Status'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, your JSON isn't valid. You have

```
{
{
    "Status":"<%= this._result.ToString().ToLower() %>" , 
    "SavePath":"<%= this.FileUrl%>" , 
    "FileName":"<%= this.Request["qqfile"] %>",
    "SizeError":"<%= this._sizeError.ToString().ToLower()%>",
    "ImgValidation":"<%=this._Imgvalid.ToString().ToLower()%>"

}
}
```

but it should be

```
{
    "Status":"<%= this._result.ToString().ToLower() %>" , 
    "SavePath":"<%= this.FileUrl%>" , 
    "FileName":"<%= this.Request["qqfile"] %>",
    "SizeError":"<%= this._sizeError.ToString().ToLower()%>",
    "ImgValidation":"<%=this._Imgvalid.ToString().ToLower()%>"

}
```

Then you can refer to the properties as responseJSON.Status, responseJSON.SavePath, etc.
A JSON object is just that - an object. If that object has no name how can you refer to it? What would be valid is

```
{
  JSONResponse:{
  "Status":"<%= this._result.ToString().ToLower() %>" , 
  "SavePath":"<%= this.FileUrl%>" , 
  "FileName":"<%= this.Request["qqfile"] %>",
  "SizeError":"<%= this._sizeError.ToString().ToLower()%>",
  "ImgValidation":"<%=this._Imgvalid.ToString().ToLower()%>"

  }
}
```